# Notepad++ Default matching tag highlight

Tags: notepad++, highlighting

When you select an initial tag the end tag slightly highlights.

I have explored the style settings, but I can not find which is the specific style I need to modify.

I normally use it for Html and php files. I use the HtmlTag plugin, but I want to find that specific style.

Do you know which one is it?

Comment: "When you select initial tag then end tag also gets highlighted" this style is present : Settings>>Style Configurator>>Languages>>SELECT Global Style>>style>>SELECT Smart Highlighting.. and choose any colour in "Background colour" option. This "smart highlighting" feature helps to change colour. You can upload your new style on Notepadd++.

Comment: Thanks Selah1936 I found it. This style you coment for some reason highlited a bar on a previous version of notepad. Funny.

Comment: So I think It's Clear now. Should I put my previous comment as an answer so that you accept it and It would be seen in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found it. The reason It was so hard to find is because it has a transparency so I did not recognized the already applied color.

It is on Global Styles > Tags Match Highlight.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these Steps:

```
Settings > Style Configurator > Languages> Global Style > Smart Highlighting..
```

choose any colour in "**Background colour**" option and click save

This "smart highlighting" feature helps to change colour.

Comment: For some reason, the Smart Highlighting does not change anithing visible. I will read more about it. I found the Tags Match. But thanks :o)

Comment: Probably I am overwriting this style with something else. But the Tag match works for me.